# Lost databases in Postgres after restart

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-ec2

Firstly I am a novice Postgres SQL user. I have installed Postgres in EC2 instance which has two volumes, one root volume, and another data volume.

I have 4 working databases and when I stop and start the instance, I am not able to connect to those databases.

These are the processes running after rebooting the machine.

```
ps aux | grep post
postgres  2569  0.0  1.3 230400 13484 ?        S    07:24   0:00 /usr/lib64/pgsql92/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql9/data
postgres  2571  0.0  0.3 190148  3748 ?        Ss   07:24   0:00 postgres: logger process                                         
postgres  2573  0.0  0.3 230400  3944 ?        Ss   07:24   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                   
postgres  2574  0.0  0.4 230400  5048 ?        Ss   07:24   0:00 postgres: writer process                                         
postgres  2575  0.0  0.3 230400  3944 ?        Ss   07:24   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                     
postgres  2576  0.0  0.6 231220  6388 ?        Ss   07:24   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                            
postgres  2577  0.0  0.4 190144  4616 ?        Ss   07:24   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                                
root      2812  0.0  0.4 192244  4084 pts/0    S    07:25   0:00 su postgres
postgres  2813  0.0  0.3 113444  3256 pts/0    S    07:25   0:00 bash
postgres  2941  0.0  0.1 115276  1988 pts/0    R+   08:15   0:00 ps aux
postgres  2942  0.0  0.1 110440  1812 pts/0    S+   08:15   0:00 grep pos
```

Could anyone please help me.

Comment: start postgresql service?.. smthlike `service postgresql start`

Comment: It is already running.

Comment: then please elaborate "I am not able to connect to those databases." - exact statements and exact errors

Comment: @VaoTsun There are no errors I am able to connect to the Postgres but when I list the databases there is only default Postgres database. I just restarted the EC2 machine that's it.

Comment: I assume you started different cluster then

Comment: Okay.data_directory is pointing to /var/lib/pgsql9/data . My actual data_directory is in /data. So how can I change the data directory?

Comment: first stop running cluster, then change config and start it back?.. or register another cluster

Comment: Thank you very much. @VaoTsun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If postgres is up and running and you don't see the databases you have, most probably you run different cluster on same port, thus connecting wth same connection string you actually connect to different cluster. If so, shutdown the running cluster and start up the right one. you could also want to edit `sysconfig` to right (not default) `data_directory`. or register new cluster with `pg_createcluster` or just use manual start up sequecne with `pg_ctl -D your_data_directory start`...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change the name of the topic because it is not about restoring database but restarting or reconnecting to them.

Then you should use psql (connected as the user postgres) to try to connect:

> psql mydb

It might not work but at least you will get more information about your problem (and be able to give them to use).

Finally, if the database where created though the Amazon web interfaces, you should check what is their status on the web interface (working, halted).

Comment: Thanks @Piervit for reply. Issue is I did not updated the PGDATA in  postgresql config file.